# C# StyleCop - Using "this." prefix for base class members like current class members or not?

Tags: c#, coding-style, this, stylecop

StyleCop has a rule about using "this." prefix to calling class members (SA1101).

Is this rule holds true about a member (for example a method) of a class which is inherited from its base class.

Example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected void F1()
    {
        ...
    }
}    

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    protected void F2()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected void F3()
    {
        this.F2(); // This is correct acording to SA1101

        // F1 is a member of base class and if I dont put this prefix, stylecop will not show any message.
        this.F1(); // Is this correct?
        F1();      // Or this?
    }
}
```

I know this is just for better readability.

Comment: Well, that's knocked trying out StyleCop way down my list of priorities, then.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: You can configure which rules are actually run. I wouldn't discount StyleCop until you take a look at it and decide which rules are important/useful for you.

Comment: @A. Karimi it is not for readability, actually use **base** would make the code more readable, it is to avoid bugs. The documentation has good sample and explanation http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1100.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **[documentation for StyleCop Rule SA1101](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/sa1101.htm)** actually mentions this:

> A violation of this rule occurs whenever the code contains a call to an instance member **of the local class or a base class** which is not prefixed with ‘this.’.

(emphasis added by myself). So yes, the rule requires `this.` on every access to an instance member, irrespective of whether that member is in the local class or inherited from a base class.

Comment: Thanks, It's interested! StyleCop will not show any message when you fogot "this." prefix for base members.

Answer (score 6):

If you think about the rules for object inheritance, even though `F1()` is actually declared on `BaseClass` it is inherited by `ChildClass` so it is valid to call it as `this.F1()`. This is what StyleCop is telling you to do. By prefixing the call with `this`, it becomes unambiguous that you are calling the `F1()` **instance** method of the current runtime instance of the class.

In fact, calling it as `F1()` or `this.F1()` are actually synonymous, but the meaning/intent becomes clearer when using the `this` prefix.

You should not use the `base` prefix here at all (even though it will compile) because `F1()` is not virtual and being overridden in `ChildClass`. The only reason to use the `base` prefix is when you have overridden a virtual base class member and want to explicitly call that base class member from within the overriding member. If you did actually use the `base` prefix without `F1()` being virtual everything *would* actually work until you made `F1()` virtual and added an override in `ChildClass`. At that point, any calls to `base.F1()` would continue calling `BaseClass.F1()` and not the new override in `ChildClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is correct since the rule holds for all methods regardless of whether they are defined on the base or not. Personally I am not a huge fan of this rule so I just disable it.

Comment: I agree with you but is there anyone or anything like stylecop which explain about that?

Answer (score -3):

I like to use base.  base.F1() for your case.  That prevents accidently referencing a local variable, and is a visual reminder of where the member came from.

Comment: It's nice but in this case we will encounter another rule in stylecop (SA1100: The call to GetItem should only use the 'base.' prefix if the item is declared virtual in the base class and an override is defined in the local class. Otherwise, prefix the call with this rather than base)

Comment: Using “base” would be really bad practice if it isn’t the base method of the current virtual method you’re calling. The base method could be made virtual and you (or someone else in the hierarchy above you) might want to override it, and then your base call would call the wrong method.

Comment: That's really bad practice. You should use base only to specify that you want the base method *instead of* one defined in that class. Calling it anywhere other than in an over-ride or hider is dodgy at best. It's prone to error and would confuse others looking at the code as they'd interpret it as being used reasonably and be confused as to why they couldn't find the over-ride or hiding method.