# C# "this" overuse?

Tags: c#, class, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use the “this” keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

I'm writing some of my first C# code, and I notice that `this.foo` is only necessary when there is a local name `foo` different from the `this.foo`. I have so far been inconsistent as to whether or not I use `this`.

Is it preferred to always use `this` or is it preferred to only use `this` when necessary?

Comment: Enter holy war.....

Comment: This has been asked a few times: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+this%20site:stackoverflow.com#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=active&q=c%23+this+keyword+required+site:stackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=5b2df7f8ff10eaf9

Comment: It's a style thing.  If you're working on your own, do whatever you'd like.  If you're part of a team, follow whatever convention has been established.

Comment: Voting to close. I'm sorry but there is no correct answer to this. Some prefer to use it, some don't. Neither is more right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use the "this" keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword) , qqv [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663215/c-stylecop-using-this-prefix-for-base-class-members-like-current-class-memb) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841807/when-not-to-use-this-keyword) etc etc

Comment: I should have known `this` was already asked.

Comment: FWIW, I searched SO before writing this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only use `this` when it is necessary. Most of the time I don't have the issue of having to differentiate between a local and class variable, so I just don't bother unless the need comes up

Answer (score 1):

I always type 'this' because it allows me to use Visual Studio's Intellisense. I don't think that there is any meaningful stylistic objection to using 'this' for each reference to an object property or method.

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Space you should be able to use Intellisense, no?

Answer (score 1):

It's really a matter of style - some people like to use `this` all the time, since it makes it clear when you're accessing a member variable instead of method local, some people use warts on the name for the same purpose, and some people don't use either.

Regardless, it's probably a bad idea to use the same name for a method local as for a member variable - the only time I'd consider it legitimate is when setting those members in the constructor or other initialization routine.

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer it because of clarity.  But also because we follow StyleCop's rules (almost all of them :) ).

[Why does StyleCop recommend prefixing method or property calls with "this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562540/why-does-stylecop-recommend-prefixing-method-or-property-calls-with-this)

Answer (score 0):

It's based entirely on your preference. I personally like to use it all the time to emphasize that it's a class variable, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

I use `this` when I want to clarify my intent.

But generally, the Visual Studio IDE will clarify the member for you (with a popup) if you hover over the member in question.  That reduces the need for `this`.

As Adam points out, typing `this` first will intellisense only the local members for you, instead of giving you the entire intellisense list.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an answer that contrasts with the many "pro this" answers...

I almost never use `this`. I prefix all member variables with an underscore, and so I can easily tell local and member variables apart. I find using `this` all the time really pollutes the code and makes it far more noisy.

Comment: I find added strange prefixes to member variables really pollutes the code and makes it far more noisy...

Comment: Plus, if you have a public member variable prefixed with an underscore, people who do lots of Python (or JavaScript) are gonna be pretty confused. :P

Comment: I find a simple underscore prefix not to be distracting (far less distracting than "this." anyway), although I do agree prefixes like "m_" are hard to swallow. And you should never have a public member variable in C# (that's a major red flag in my book, use properties please). In JS, Python, etc different languages call for different styles.

Comment: Interesting - when being used purely for readability or disambiguation, I consider both underscores and "this." to be similarly poluting. This is a point on which I happen to disagree with Style Cop - I don't use them, but I don't think it's worth the Holy War it's become.  Do what works for you and your team.